# How can I copy a pseudo variable in CMD? I'm trying to automate the copying of part of the date into the clipboard

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd, echo

What I want to have happen is when I open a batch file, the date will automatically be copied into the clipboard in the format of month.day.

In cmd, when I type in `%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%` it outputs the date perfectly, but I can't seem to get it to automatically add it to the clipboard.  Do you guys have any ideas?

Here's the code that I've tried to get to work:

`start cmd.exe /c "%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2% /t | clip"`

When I try this, the console outputs the following: '05.26' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: simply do `echo %date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%|clip.exe`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!  Haha, sorry I'm really new to cmd and .bat so it was a really basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `echo` to display the time which will be captured by `clip`.

Try with this:

```
start "" cmd /c "echo %date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2% | clip"
```